# Get subarray based on object property

Tags: ruby

Say I have a model `Person`. The model `Person` has an attribute `age`.

If I have an array of `Person`-objects, how may I return a subarray containing only the `Person`-objects whose `age`-attribute is equal to, say, 20?

Comment: if it is an `ActiveRecord` model, `Person.where(:age => 20)` seems like the best thing to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes use [`select`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-select) method.

```
 persons.select { |person| person.age == 20 }
```